# Is there any way to define app.Table without using Record in faust?

Tags: python, faust

I'm currently using schema registry and `faust` to process stream data.

The reason I try to avoid using `faust.Record` is the schema can be dynamically changed and I don't like to change the code(class inheriting `faust.Record`) every time it happend.

But without `faust.Record`, it looks like there are many restrictions.
For example, `app.Table`'s `relative_to_field` requires `FieldDescriptorT` but this class looks stronly coupled with `faust.Record`

Here is the code:

```
import faust

from datetime import timedelta
from pydantic_avro.base import AvroBase

from schema_registry.client import SchemaRegistryClient, schema
from schema_registry.serializers.faust import FaustSerializer


topic_name = "practice4"
subject_name = f"{topic_name}-value"
serializer_name = f"{topic_name}_serializer"
bootstrap_server = "192.168.59.100:30887"

sr_server = "http://localhost:8081"

client = SchemaRegistryClient({"url": sr_server})
topic_schema = client.get_schema(subject_name)

fp_avro_schema = schema.AvroSchema(topic_schema.schema.raw_schema)

avro_fp_serializer = FaustSerializer(client, serializer_name, fp_avro_schema)
faust.serializers.codecs.register(name=serializer_name, codec=avro_fp_serializer)

app = faust.App('sample_app', broker=bootstrap_server)
faust_topic = app.topic(topic_name, value_serializer=serializer_name)


count_table = app.Table(
    'count_table', default=int,
).hopping(
    timedelta(minutes=10),
    timedelta(minutes=5),
    expires=timedelta(minutes=10)
).relative_to_field(??????)


@app.agent(faust_topic)
async def process_fp(fps):
    async for fp in fps.group_by(lambda fp: fp["job_id"], name=f"{subject_name}.job_id"):     
        print(fp)
```

Luckily, stream's `group_by` can be called with `callable` object, so I can handle it with `lambda` but table's `relative_to_field` has no option such like that.

Comment: Be careful with `hopping` table in `faust`. The implementation is quite wrong for a standard use case. There is a [PR](https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust/pull/412) to fix this issue. I recommend you to check the comment and patch the way window are handled to have a "normal" behaviour".

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, you're right, you cannot define `relative_to_field` without a `FieldDescriptor`. You can check the definiton of `relative_to_field` [here](https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust/blob/ce53c406ec97615c66b8f6551b1efa45c90f0a6b/faust/tables/wrappers.py#L369). Then, this field is extracted [here](https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust/blob/ce53c406ec97615c66b8f6551b1efa45c90f0a6b/faust/tables/base.py#L542) with a `getattr`, you need a `faust.Record` for this operation.

**However**, as you use `Avro` you may use the library [dataclasses-avroschema](https://github.com/marcosschroh/dataclasses-avroschema) to combine `faust.Record` and `Avro` in the same class. Thus, you will be able to use best of both world.

This library integrates well with faust as you can see in [doc](https://marcosschroh.github.io/dataclasses-avroschema/faust_records/).